# Ошибка при запуске на сервере приложения с GUI

Tags: linux, gui, клиент-сервер, библиотеки

Пытаюсь запустить приложение с GUI, использующее `gstream` на устройстве `Orange Pi Zero`. Для этого использую виртуальный фрейм буфер `xvfb`:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x16 &
export DISPLAY=:1.0
<приложение с параметрами>
```

В ответ каждую секунду получаю ошибку:

> GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed

При этом, если попробовать те же манипуляции на компьютере (перейдя в текстовый режим посредством Ctrl+Alt+F1), все работает.

Пытался найти решение в гугле - на эту ошибку ведет множество страниц, но ни на одной из них решения я не нашел.

В тоже время, другие приложения, для которых требуется X-сервер (настройки `gsetting`, какой-нибудь `Xclock`) спокойно запускаются (я их не вижу в терминале конечно, но но я не получаю обычной ошибки `Can't open display: :0.0`

По всей видимости, ошибка довольно критична, т.к. приложение не начинает и не останавливает свою работу (авто-старт записи звука), как делает это в текстовом режиме работы на компьютере. Правда, если указать ей начать запись в параметрах запуска, то запись начнется и согласно настроек потом сама закончит запись), но такой вариант меня не устраивает.
Программа на компьютере и устройстве настроена одинаково.

Comment: просто программа написана криво. в эмуляторе терминала её запустите (на той же системе) и убедитесь, что это не критическая информация.

Comment: Эта ошибка пишется многими приложениями даже в рабочем состоянии и к неработоспособности скорее всего не имет отношения

Comment: Хм, спасибо за комментарии, приму к сведению. Самое обидное, что вчера я как-то смог от неё избавиться, ночью лёг спать, с утра решил продолжить работать и снова она, но уже никак её не могу убрать.

Comment: Нет, по всей видимости, это связано с чем-то существенным, т.к. программа не делает того, что должна (не начинает запись звука автоматически), в то время как на компьютере в текстовом режиме она это делает.